# JSF2.0: EL are not resolved in a Composite Component taglib

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I'm trying to create a custom composite component taglib in my office but i get a strange issue with EL. It seems expressions as #{cc.attrs.[var] } are already resolve as empty.

I try to create my taglib in a jar. In my jar i have my files ordered as following:

|_ /

.....|_ META-INF

..........|_ compo.taglib.xml

..........|_ resources

...............|_ components

....................|_ hello.xhtml

compo.taglib.xml contains:

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<namespace>http://www.example.com/jsf/compo</namespace>
<composite-library-name>compo</composite-library-name>
<tag>
<tag-name>hello</tag-name>
<source>./components/hello.xhtml</source>
</tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

hello.xhtml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface name="hello" displayName="hello">
<composite:attribute name="name" required="true" type="String"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation >
hello #{cc.attrs.name}!
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

My web project contains in WEB-INF lib my taglib as a jar, jsf-impl.jar and jsf-api.jar (from Mojarra) my page is simply that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:comp="http://www.example.com/jsf/compo" >
<body>
<comp:hello name="John"></comp:hello>
</body>
</html>
```

At rendering i see "hello !" but not "hello John!". Attributes values seems be lost somewhere. I try this sample on tomcat 6.0.29 and Websphere 7.

I made something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested your control in web application rather than from taglib (jar file)? 
I can only guess but I think your attribute is not showing because you named it **name**. In some cases "name" attribute is beeing used by JSF (for example in **f:attribute** or **f:param** or even **ui:param** uses attribute **name**). Try to replace attribute name with oder word.

You need to look [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/) and check if attribute name is available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this case appears also with other attributes. 
I tried with the component in web application and issue doesn't appear.
I also tried with the component in a jar with default namespace: issue doesn't appear. I think there is bug when using composite component in a jar with custom namespace.